# Analytical solution(root) for a tenth order polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

is it possible to develop an analytical solution (root) for such a polynomial:
$f(x)=\left(x^{10}-c_1^2\right)\left(c_2-x\right)^2-0.2\left(x^2-1\right)c_1^2$ with
$c_1$ and $c_2 >0$.

Numerical methods can help, however, the convergence speed is not as satisfactory as desired.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution?  Do you mean roots?

Comment: @RonGordon, yes, that is exactly what I mean

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem

Comment: @par, it should be noted that there are polynomials with degree $\geq 5$ whose zeros can be written in closed form.

Comment: @user2536125, there may be asymptotic approximations to the solutions depending on the relative sizes of the parameters.  About how large are $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas , $c_1\in \left[0,1\right]$, $c_2\in\left[0,1.5\right]$and $x\in\left[0,1.5\right]$